# How to select multiple label columns for the Tensorflow time series tutorial?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, tensorflow

I have been following [this tutorial for an autoregressive RNN](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#advanced_autoregressive_model) for Tensorflow, and I have realized that the time series tutorial only supports labels either for one column or for all columns, selecting multiple columns (in the WindowGenerator class) from the data throws an error, and I cannot figure out what needs to be changed in the code to support this.  Here is the complete code to replicate the problem when run:

```py
import os
import datetime

import IPython
import IPython.display
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import tensorflow as tf

mpl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (8, 6)
mpl.rcParams['axes.grid'] = False

zip_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    origin='https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/jena_climate_2009_2016.csv.zip',
    fname='jena_climate_2009_2016.csv.zip',
    extract=True)
csv_path, _ = os.path.splitext(zip_path)

df = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
# slice [start:stop:step], starting from index 5 take every 6th record.
df = df[5::6]

date_time = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('Date Time'), format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')

wv = df['wv (m/s)']
bad_wv = wv == -9999.0
wv[bad_wv] = 0.0

max_wv = df['max. wv (m/s)']
bad_max_wv = max_wv == -9999.0
max_wv[bad_max_wv] = 0.0

wv = df.pop('wv (m/s)')
max_wv = df.pop('max. wv (m/s)')

# Convert to radians.
wd_rad = df.pop('wd (deg)')*np.pi / 180

# Calculate the wind x and y components.
df['Wx'] = wv*np.cos(wd_rad)
df['Wy'] = wv*np.sin(wd_rad)

# Calculate the max wind x and y components.
df['max Wx'] = max_wv*np.cos(wd_rad)
df['max Wy'] = max_wv*np.sin(wd_rad)

timestamp_s = date_time.map(datetime.datetime.timestamp)
day = 24*60*60
year = (365.2425)*day

df['Day sin'] = np.sin(timestamp_s * (2 * np.pi / day))
df['Day cos'] = np.cos(timestamp_s * (2 * np.pi / day))
df['Year sin'] = np.sin(timestamp_s * (2 * np.pi / year))
df['Year cos'] = np.cos(timestamp_s * (2 * np.pi / year))

column_indices = {name: i for i, name in enumerate(df.columns)}

n = len(df)
train_df = df[0:int(n*0.7)]
val_df = df[int(n*0.7):int(n*0.9)]
test_df = df[int(n*0.9):]

num_features = df.shape[1]

train_mean = train_df.mean()
train_std = train_df.std()

train_df = (train_df - train_mean) / train_std
val_df = (val_df - train_mean) / train_std
test_df = (test_df - train_mean) / train_std

class WindowGenerator():
    def __init__(self, input_width, label_width, shift,
                   train_df=train_df, val_df=val_df, test_df=test_df,
                   label_columns=None):
        # Store the raw data.
        self.train_df = train_df
        self.val_df = val_df
        self.test_df = test_df

        # Work out the label column indices.
        self.label_columns = label_columns
        if label_columns is not None:
            self.label_columns_indices = {name: i for i, name in
                                        enumerate(label_columns)}
        self.column_indices = {name: i for i, name in
                               enumerate(train_df.columns)}

        # Work out the window parameters.
        self.input_width = input_width
        self.label_width = label_width
        self.shift = shift

        self.total_window_size = input_width + shift

        self.input_slice = slice(0, input_width)
        self.input_indices = np.arange(self.total_window_size)[self.input_slice]

        self.label_start = self.total_window_size - self.label_width
        self.labels_slice = slice(self.label_start, None)
        self.label_indices = np.arange(self.total_window_size)[self.labels_slice]

    def __repr__(self):
        return '\n'.join([
            f'Total window size: {self.total_window_size}',
            f'Input indices: {self.input_indices}',
            f'Label indices: {self.label_indices}',
            f'Label column name(s): {self.label_columns}'])

    def split_window(self, features):
        inputs = features[:, self.input_slice, :]
        labels = features[:, self.labels_slice, :]
        if self.label_columns is not None:
          labels = tf.stack(
              [labels[:, :, self.column_indices[name]] for name in self.label_columns],
              axis=-1)

        # Slicing doesn't preserve static shape information, so set the shapes
        # manually. This way the `tf.data.Datasets` are easier to inspect.
        inputs.set_shape([None, self.input_width, None])
        labels.set_shape([None, self.label_width, None])

        return inputs, labels
    def plot(self, model=None, plot_col='T (degC)', max_subplots=3):
        inputs, labels = self.example
        plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
        plot_col_index = self.column_indices[plot_col]
        max_n = min(max_subplots, len(inputs))
        for n in range(max_n):
          plt.subplot(3, 1, n+1)
          plt.ylabel(f'{plot_col} [normed]')
          plt.plot(self.input_indices, inputs[n, :, plot_col_index],
                   label='Inputs', marker='.', zorder=-10)

          if self.label_columns:
            label_col_index = self.label_columns_indices.get(plot_col, None)
          else:
            label_col_index = plot_col_index

          if label_col_index is None:
            continue

          plt.scatter(self.label_indices, labels[n, :, label_col_index],
                      edgecolors='k', label='Labels', c='#2ca02c', s=64)
          if model is not None:
            predictions = model(inputs)
            plt.scatter(self.label_indices, predictions[n, :, label_col_index],
                        marker='X', edgecolors='k', label='Predictions',
                        c='#ff7f0e', s=64)

          if n == 0:
            plt.legend()

        plt.xlabel('Time [h]')
    def make_dataset(self, data):
        data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float32)
        ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
            data=data,
            targets=None,
            sequence_length=self.total_window_size,
            sequence_stride=1,
            shuffle=True,
            batch_size=32,)

        ds = ds.map(self.split_window)

        return ds
    @property
    def train(self):
        return self.make_dataset(self.train_df)

    @property
    def val(self):
        return self.make_dataset(self.val_df)

    @property
    def test(self):
        return self.make_dataset(self.test_df)

    @property
    def example(self):
        """Get and cache an example batch of `inputs, labels` for plotting."""
        result = getattr(self, '_example', None)
        if result is None:
            # No example batch was found, so get one from the `.train` dataset
            result = next(iter(self.train))
            # And cache it for next time
            self._example = result
        return result

class FeedBack(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, units, out_steps):
        super().__init__()
        self.out_steps = out_steps
        self.units = units
        self.lstm_cell = tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(units)
        # Also wrap the LSTMCell in an RNN to simplify the `warmup` method.
        self.lstm_rnn = tf.keras.layers.RNN(self.lstm_cell, return_state=True)
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_features)

    def warmup(self, inputs):
        # inputs.shape => (batch, time, features)
        # x.shape => (batch, lstm_units)
        x, *state = self.lstm_rnn(inputs)

        # predictions.shape => (batch, features)
        prediction = self.dense(x)
        return prediction, state

    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        # Use a TensorArray to capture dynamically unrolled outputs.
        predictions = []
        # Initialize the lstm state
        prediction, state = self.warmup(inputs)

        # Insert the first prediction
        predictions.append(prediction)

        # Run the rest of the prediction steps
        for n in range(1, self.out_steps):
            # Use the last prediction as input.
            x = prediction
            # Execute one lstm step.
            x, state = self.lstm_cell(x, states=state,
                                      training=training)
            # Convert the lstm output to a prediction.
            prediction = self.dense(x)
            # Add the prediction to the output
            predictions.append(prediction)

        # predictions.shape => (time, batch, features)
        predictions = tf.stack(predictions)
        # predictions.shape => (batch, time, features)
        predictions = tf.transpose(predictions, [1, 0, 2])
        return predictions

MAX_EPOCHS = 1

def compile_and_fit(model, window, patience=2):
    early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                                                      patience=patience,
                                                      mode='min')

    model.compile(loss=tf.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
                  optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(),
                  metrics=[tf.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()])

    history = model.fit(window.train, epochs=MAX_EPOCHS,
                        validation_data=window.val,
                        callbacks=[early_stopping])
    return history

OUT_STEPS = 24
multi_window = WindowGenerator(input_width=24,
                               label_width=OUT_STEPS,
                               shift=OUT_STEPS,label_columns=['T (degC)','p (mbar)'])

feedback_model = FeedBack(units=32, out_steps=OUT_STEPS)
prediction, state = feedback_model.warmup(multi_window.example[0])

history = compile_and_fit(feedback_model, multi_window)
```

Output:

```py
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 19 and 2 for '{{node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}} = SquaredDifference[T=DT_FLOAT](feed_back/transpose, IteratorGetNext:1)' with input shapes: [?,24,19], [?,24,2].
```

Comment: Please frame question as an MRE. This is far from Minimal.

Comment: @noah The code provided should be fairly complete, making it unnecessary for users to take code directly from the tutorial page, in addition to excluding the other extraneous steps in the tutorial not needed for this specific model. Although, I don't think I see python notebooks posted to SO for debugging. The question now also has a Github issue. If the code snippet there would better constitute an MRE for SO then I will update this question accordingly: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/46773.